# Query to join two tables in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the two tables:

```
TABLE1 (currency nchar(3), seq int)
TABLE2 (code, currency nchar(3), seq int, value money)
```

Sample data for `TABLE1`

```
currency    seq
USD          1
EUR          2
CNY          3
GBP          4
```

Sample data for `TABLE2`

```
code     currency       seq    value
111       USD            1     650,90
111       AED            5     330,80

222       USD             1     540,90
222       GBP             4     778,40
222       EUR             2     290,30
```

Now I need to add to `TABLE2` currencies from `TABLE1` but only those, that are missing in `TABLE2` for certain `code`.

Sample output:

```
   code    currency     seq    value
   111       USD         1     650,90
   111       AED         5     330,80      --this currency should stay even it is not in TABLE1
   111       EUR         2     NULL        --this currency was missing for code 111
   111       CNY         3     NULL        --this currency was missing for code 111
   111       GBP         4     NULL        --this currency was missing for code 111

   222       USD         1     540,90
   222       GBP         4     778,40
   222       EUR         2     290,30
   222       CNY         3     NULL       --this currency was missing for code 222
```

I could show my attempts to build a query but they all fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query and see if it helps:

```
insert into TABLE2 (code, currency, seq, value)
select t.GroupCode, t.currency, t.seq, NULL
from
(
    select t2.code as GroupCode, t1.currency, t1.seq
    from (select code, currency from TABLE2 group by code, currency) t2
    cross join TABLE1 t1 ) t
left join (select code, currency from TABLE2 group by code, currency) t3
on t.currency = t3.currency
where t3.code is null
group by t.GroupCode, t.currency, t.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Insert Into TABLE2 (currency,seq)
  select currency,seq from Table1 t1 where t1.currency  not in (select currency   from Table2)
```

Comment: You want Insert Only currency From The Table 1 ,If You Want Add Code also than Table  must  have Code Column also ..

Comment: No, I cannot add 'code' to table1, I'm sure there is a way using joins and grouping.